# <hr> element disappears after adding a <div class="row"> (bootstrap) element

Tags: html

I'm writing a landing page using bootstrap 4.3.1. 
After adding the "row" div, the horizontal ruler disappears and I just can't get it back.
The funny thing is when I'm adding the commented section tag, I can see the horizontal line again.

Any suggestions to why it happens/how to make the horizontal line visible again without the section tag?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <header class="text-center">
      <h1 class="text-uppercase"><strong>The biggest startup event of the year</strong></h1>
    </header>
    <!-- <section> -->
      <hr>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find out more</button>
    <!-- </section> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is bit confusing as hr tag gives the horizontal line with width=100% and the row occupy a horizontal row

so think again is this possible, try to close the div of rows and then try to put the hr tag

```
  <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
        <header class="text-center">
        <h1 class="text-uppercase"><strong>The biggest startup event of theyear</strong></h1>
        </header>
        </div>
        <!-- <section> -->
        <hr>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find out more</button>
        <!-- </section> -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok. I roughly understand what you're trying to say. Your change fix it of course.
BUT. I get the point that the row occupies a horizontal row, but why couldn't I see the horizontal line inside it? That's what I can't understand.

Comment: if you try to put the <hr> inside the row  it will divide the row in to two section upper and lower so the other components assignment in the row is not possible so try to take row on note book and drow hr inside it you will get to knew